# Markered detected common elements on two images (OpenCV) - PYTHON

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I found some example solution a detected common element on the two images.
It's code on Python with OpenCV and I execute on my two examples images:

```python
'''
Feature-based image matching sample.
Note, that you will need the https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib repo for SIFT and SURF
USAGE
  find_obj.py [--feature=<sift|surf|orb|akaze|brisk>[-flann]] [ <image1> <image2> ]
  --feature  - Feature to use. Can be sift, surf, orb or brisk. Append '-flann'
               to feature name to use Flann-based matcher instead bruteforce.
  Press left mouse button on a feature point to see its matching point.
'''

    # Python 2/3 compatibility
    from __future__ import print_function

    import numpy as np
    import cv2 as cv
    from common import anorm, getsize

    FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1  # bug: flann enums are missing
    FLANN_INDEX_LSH    = 6


    def init_feature(name):
        chunks = name.split('-')
        if chunks[0] == 'sift':
            detector = cv.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
            norm = cv.NORM_L2
        elif chunks[0] == 'surf':
            detector = cv.xfeatures2d.SURF_create(200)
            norm = cv.NORM_L2
        elif chunks[0] == 'orb':
            detector = cv.ORB_create(1400)
            norm = cv.NORM_HAMMING
        elif chunks[0] == 'akaze':
            detector = cv.AKAZE_create()
            norm = cv.NORM_HAMMING
        elif chunks[0] == 'brisk':
            detector = cv.BRISK_create()
            norm = cv.NORM_HAMMING
        else:
            return None, None
        if 'flann' in chunks:
            if norm == cv.NORM_L2:
                flann_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
            else:
                flann_params= dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_LSH,
                                   table_number = 6, # 12
                                   key_size = 12,     # 20
                                   multi_probe_level = 1) #2
            matcher = cv.FlannBasedMatcher(flann_params, {})  # bug : need to pass empty dict (#1329)
        else:
            matcher = cv.BFMatcher(norm)
        return detector, matcher


    def filter_matches(kp1, kp2, matches, ratio = 0.75):
        mkp1, mkp2 = [], []
        for m in matches:
            if len(m) == 2 and m[0].distance < m[1].distance * ratio:
                m = m[0]
                mkp1.append( kp1[m.queryIdx] )
                mkp2.append( kp2[m.trainIdx] )
        p1 = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in mkp1])
        p2 = np.float32([kp.pt for kp in mkp2])
        kp_pairs = zip(mkp1, mkp2)
        return p1, p2, list(kp_pairs)

    def explore_match(win, img1, img2, kp_pairs, status = None, H = None):
        h1, w1 = img1.shape[:2]
        h2, w2 = img2.shape[:2]
        vis = np.zeros((max(h1, h2), w1+w2), np.uint8)
        vis[:h1, :w1] = img1
        vis[:h2, w1:w1+w2] = img2
        vis = cv.cvtColor(vis, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

        if H is not None:
            corners = np.float32([[0, 0], [w1, 0], [w1, h1], [0, h1]])
            corners = np.int32( cv.perspectiveTransform(corners.reshape(1, -1, 2), H).reshape(-1, 2) + (w1, 0) )
            cv.polylines(vis, [corners], True, (255, 255, 255))

        if status is None:
            status = np.ones(len(kp_pairs), np.bool_)
        p1, p2 = [], []  # python 2 / python 3 change of zip unpacking
        for kpp in kp_pairs:
            p1.append(np.int32(kpp[0].pt))
            p2.append(np.int32(np.array(kpp[1].pt) + [w1, 0]))

        green = (0, 255, 0)
        red = (0, 0, 255)
        kp_color = (51, 103, 236)
        for (x1, y1), (x2, y2), inlier in zip(p1, p2, status):
            if inlier:
                col = green
                cv.circle(vis, (x1, y1), 2, col, -1)
                cv.circle(vis, (x2, y2), 2, col, -1)
            else:
                col = red
                r = 2
                thickness = 3
                cv.line(vis, (x1-r, y1-r), (x1+r, y1+r), col, thickness)
                cv.line(vis, (x1-r, y1+r), (x1+r, y1-r), col, thickness)
                cv.line(vis, (x2-r, y2-r), (x2+r, y2+r), col, thickness)
                cv.line(vis, (x2-r, y2+r), (x2+r, y2-r), col, thickness)
        vis0 = vis.copy()
        for (x1, y1), (x2, y2), inlier in zip(p1, p2, status):
            if inlier:
                cv.line(vis, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), green)

        cv.imshow(win, vis)

        def onmouse(event, x, y, flags, param):
            cur_vis = vis
            if flags & cv.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON:
                cur_vis = vis0.copy()
                r = 8
                m = (anorm(np.array(p1) - (x, y)) < r) | (anorm(np.array(p2) - (x, y)) < r)
                idxs = np.where(m)[0]

                kp1s, kp2s = [], []
                for i in idxs:
                    (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = p1[i], p2[i]
                    col = (red, green)[status[i][0]]
                    cv.line(cur_vis, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), col)
                    kp1, kp2 = kp_pairs[i]
                    kp1s.append(kp1)
                    kp2s.append(kp2)
                cur_vis = cv.drawKeypoints(cur_vis, kp1s, None, flags=4, color=kp_color)
                cur_vis[:,w1:] = cv.drawKeypoints(cur_vis[:,w1:], kp2s, None, flags=4, color=kp_color)

            cv.imshow(win, cur_vis)
        cv.setMouseCallback(win, onmouse)
        return vis


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        print(__doc__)

        import sys, getopt
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], '', ['feature='])
        opts = dict(opts)
        feature_name = opts.get('--feature', 'brisk')
        try:
            fn1, fn2 = args
        except:
            fn1 = '../data/box.png'
            fn2 = '../data/box_in_scene.png'

        img1 = cv.imread(fn1, 0)
        img2 = cv.imread(fn2, 0)
        detector, matcher = init_feature(feature_name)

        if img1 is None:
            print('Failed to load fn1:', fn1)
            sys.exit(1)

        if img2 is None:
            print('Failed to load fn2:', fn2)
            sys.exit(1)

        if detector is None:
            print('unknown feature:', feature_name)
            sys.exit(1)

        print('using', feature_name)

        kp1, desc1 = detector.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
        kp2, desc2 = detector.detectAndCompute(img2, None)
        print('img1 - %d features, img2 - %d features' % (len(kp1), len(kp2)))

        def match_and_draw(win):
            print('matching...')
            raw_matches = matcher.knnMatch(desc1, trainDescriptors = desc2, k = 2) #2
            p1, p2, kp_pairs = filter_matches(kp1, kp2, raw_matches)
            if len(p1) >= 4:
                H, status = cv.findHomography(p1, p2, cv.RANSAC, 5.0)
                print('%d / %d  inliers/matched' % (np.sum(status), len(status)))
            else:
                H, status = None, None
                print('%d matches found, not enough for homography estimation' % len(p1))

            _vis = explore_match(win, img1, img2, kp_pairs, status, H)

        match_and_draw('find_obj')
        cv.waitKey()
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Its original images
[image]

Its images with some changes
[image]

And result in Python Code like this:

```
 python diff_good.py --feature=surf  images/org_web.png images/change1.png
```

Result detected common object
[image]

I try to find some solution - how change markered type of common object for example: instead show area with many colors point to some contours, shape (square, rectangle etc.) something like this :

This is some example second images with markered by green rectangles commons element - block
example result images
[image]

I want to change this code to get markered only common contours - the area without many points or line like now, because it's not clear to present and understood.

Maybe will be the best solution make third images - result output image with markered only common area like rectangles objects or contours.

But after many hours spend for search solution on google, forums and groups I failed to change this code to act as it needs, maybe here I will find some help, example or suggestions how to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I found this repo [x-img-diff](https://github.com/Quramy/x-img-diff).
They cluster the keypoints into the same boxes and use some other methods to handle the boxes. You can try this way.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).